# Finding left cosets of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \left<a\right>$ be a cyclic group such that $|a| = 30$. How many left cosets of $\left<a^4\right>$ in $G$ are there?

So we know that $|G|=30$ and $|\left<a^4\right>|=\frac{30}{\gcd(30,4)}=15$. Now we have to check how many times we can partition $G$ using $\left<a^4\right>$. One obvious left cost is $e\left<a^4\right>=\left<a^4\right>$ which has $15$ elements. If we multiply by any $a^k\in G$, we will get this same amount of elements. I am confused how this partitions the group however. Any help or hint appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There are $30$ elements in the group, and $15$ elements in each coset. The cosets don't overlap. So how many cosets are there?

Answer (score 1):

Any two left cosets of $\langle a^4\rangle$ are either the same or disjoint. Since each left coset has 15 elements, there must be 2 total (that's the amount needed to cover the group).

Answer (score 0):

It has to be the index of $\langle a^4\rangle $ in $G$, which is $30/15=2$.